# Empty guava cache size?

Tags: java, caching, google-guava-cache

Just wondering if the system pre-allocate any space for empty guava cache? I am new to guava cache, can someone help me to understand this problem?

Also I test it with code below:

```
    long preMemUsage = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() -Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    Cache<String, CountObject> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .maximumSize(12000)
        .expireAfterAccess(7200,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .concurrencyLevel(10)
        .recordStats().build();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long postMemUsage = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    System.out.println("Before: " + preMemUsage);
    System.out.println("After: " + postMemUsage);
```

The weird thing is the used memory is decreased after..... no idea why.
Can someone explain this.

Thanks a lot : )

Comment: Mysterious are the ways of garbage collector. It's pretty much possible and you should call garbage collector explicitly before trying to calculate used memory. `System.gc()`

Answer (score 1):

Mysterious are the ways of garbage collector. It's pretty much possible and you should call garbage collector explicitly before trying to calculate used memory. Use `System.gc()` right before calculating `preMemUsage` and `postMemUsage` and you should get much more accurate results.

Comment: I can't see where exactly and how are you calculating `preMemUsage`

Comment: same as postMemUsage,   although I don't think System.gc() make any difference,  I tried.  It turns out the memory usage drops still. : )

Comment: Have you tried to "wait" (`Thread.sleep`) before the measurement?